# SqlQuery(): A member of the type, 'id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

**Error:**

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified
>   '[table name]'. A member of the type, 'id', does
>   not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Hello,

I'm executing a SQL query using [`.SqlQuery()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679117(v=vs.113).aspx). When I do a regular `SELECT *`, the statement executes fine. But when I add a `Group By` clause, I receive the above error. I don't understand what this means. I have an ID column in the table. Here's the two SQL statements:

**Works**:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM <table name>
```

**Throws Error**:

```
SELECT YEAR(VisitDate) FROM <table name> GROUP BY YEAR(VisitDate)
```

Here is the Entity Mode for that table:

[image]

Comment: You have ID in your EDMX; Do you really have the same in your Table? One quick suggestions is to remove this table from EDMX and re-add

Comment: The groupby statement only returns `YEAR(VisitDate)`, as an unnamed column too. The result columns should match *all* properties in the entity model by name and type.

Answer (score 0):

Your `EDMX` looks like out of synchronization with your actual table.  Try performing below steps:

1. Open `EDMX`
2. Right-click in the white area and click **Update Model from Database...**
3. Select **Refresh** tab
4. Expand Tables; select the table you want to update
5. Click **Finish**

OR

1. Open `EDMX`
2. Right-click the table you get error, click **Delete from Model**
3. Right-click in the white area, click **Update Model from Database...**
4. Under **Add** tab, select the table you removed
5. Click **Finish**